# How do I add a search bar to my header?

Tags: css, search, headers

I need to add a functioning search bar to my header. I have read through the forums but am unsure what code I need to put where. For instance, where do I put the css code versus where do I put the html code. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 10):

Just add to your theme this code:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

This code will echoing search form so place it everywhere where you want to have the search form.

Further you need to have `search.php` file in your theme which will show the search results. You can use ordinary WP loop in the file.